# maven-shade-plugin vs maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: hadoop, maven-assembly-plugin, classnotfound, maven-shade-plugin, spring-data-hadoop

I wrote a hadoop MR job using spring-data-hadoop and used maven-shade-plugin to pack all necessary jars.
But when I ran the job from comand line:hadoop jar  , it gave me Exception for ClassNotFound for the spring-beans.
Resulting problem in loading spring application context. 
There after I used maven-assembly-plugin and packed all required jars in a lib folder. This time it worked.

I fail to understand why did it failed with maven-shade-plugin. Can someone help me understand my observation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you used a shade plugin but I'd assume that you may get into trouble with meta info like `META-INF/spring.handlers` and `META-INF/spring.schemas` which have same path in all spring jars.

Answer (score 1):

From http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

> This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar, including its dependencies and to shade - i.e. rename - the packages of some of the dependencies.

I'm guessing your configuration of the shade plugin had renamed some packages such that the class files could no longer be found.